# How to set the toogle switch control on/off dynamically by binding it for window phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

Actually I have taken the toogleswitch in the List box and it is generated dynamically.
And I am binding the database fields values to the list box.
and there is a field "Selected" which has values 0/1.
So I want the switch to be On/Off based on that value.
Also tell me How would I get the particular List Item on the toogleswitch change. because I want to change the Database field( Name of field is "Selected") for the particular row in the list box

```
cs Code
___________

List<Audit_Group> groupSectionList = e.Parameter as List<Audit_Group>;
lbGroupSection.ItemsSource = groupSectionList; // lbGroupSection is the ListBox

.xaml code
_________________
<ListBox x:Name="lbGroupSection" Foreground="Black" Margin="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Width="auto">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">-->
                            <!--ONE ROW-->
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="tbSectionName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Section_Name}" FontSize="20"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Grid Background="White">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                           <ColumnDefinition Width="270"></ColumnDefinition>
                                           <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="tbGroupName" Text="{Binding Group_Name}" FontSize="20"/>
                                     <ToggleSwitch x:Name="tsGroup" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="tsGroup_Toggled" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchButtonStyle1}" /> /* How to make it On/Off based on the DB field value */
                                 </Grid>
                              </Border>
                          </StackPanel>
                        <!--END ONE ROW-->
                   <!--</Border>-->
               </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a converter that returns bool depending upon your dynamic value(return true for 1 and false for 0) bind the value to the selected property of the toggle button via the converter. That should solve it.

Comment: I have tried to use converter but the problem with that conversion code is , If I change the Model class attribute set property then I will not be able to set any other value to the same attribute again(because each time it will keep converting the value that I set) i.e in DB again. Because each time it will convert the set value.
 
 So if possible would you upload here the appropriate conversion code So that I can try to implement it in my project.

Comment: so you are making db operations for every user interaction(toggle)?

Comment: Yes I am getting the collection(List<model class>) from the DB and each row has a selected field which consists of 0/1 value.

 So based on that value I want to show  the switch on/Off...
 also I want to avoid the page from refreshing
 and the user can also on/off the switch again ..
 and I am updating the Selected field in the DB.

Comment: Normally,my approach would be to read the db content when apage is activated and have thay content in viewmodel. When the page is left, make write db operation